# How to do overloaded closed-kinesthetic-chain pushups without a spotter?

Tags: muscle, bodybuilding, push-ups

Muscle & Fitness [says](http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/workout-routines/explosive-closed-and-open-chain-workouts-mass-gain?page=3)

> Most chest and shoulder closed-chain exercises **aren't** practical for
>   developing strength, so these routines substitute the incline barbell
>   press and barbell overhead press. (emphasis mine)

Yet, a small lady friend sitting on my back while doing push ups works well, gets a nice burn, and feels pretty cool. Now, how to do this without a spotter/partner/lady friend? I thought about throwing plates into a backpack, but that looks awkward. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

- push-ups with a weighted west if available
- push-ups with a band (ex. Iron woody bands)
- one arm push-ups
- push-ups with a sandbag
- push-ups with chains
- push-ups with a bulgarian bag
- increasing the range of motion creates also a kind of overload